# Does anyone use Iron speed designer for rapid asp.net development?

Tags: asp.net, gui-designer, ironspeed

Visual studio is pretty good but doesn't create stored procedures automatically.  Iron Speed designer does supposedly.  But is it any good?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have used Ironspeed extensively for the past two years for most of our ASP.NET forms over data projects.

It works. Does several things well: stored procs, fast layout of table browse and CRUD screens, fast layout of single record CRUD screens. It manages the round-trip (or half-round trip) process decently, detecting changes in your back end db schema and updating its data access layer, then making the changed columns available for you to alter your UI (in record or table control panels). ISD (as they call it) does an excellent job in making security management for your app pretty painless, even down to the control level (if you use ISD's subclassed versions of asp.net controls). Final plus, not a small one, is the CSS-based theme control (easy to change to a variety of themes, easy to customize a particular theme, and not even too bad to build your own theme variant by forking an existing one you like). Depending upon whether you let ISD create your stored procs in the code base or the database, changing DB's at run time can be a piece of cake.

Fairly active forum with a core group of helpful contributors. You can probably avoid the paid tech support through the forum.

Okay, the down sides. Creates fairly large code conglomerations, being a three tiered architecture. As Galwegian says, like any framework, you've got the velvet handcuffs (get your mind out of the gutter if you are thinking about anything other than code limitations and conventions!). The velvet handcuffs are the page and control model, the data layer, lack of a business object/class capability per se, the postback model, and the temptation to make your user GUI look like THEIR user GUI that comes out of the box because it is so darned easy and convenient.

ISD builds a basic page by combining an HTML template (in to which you place ISD specific code generation tags and any other tags, etc., you which using the ISD GUI or by hand). The page model relies upon a code behind page created from a piece of code template. The base classes are almost completely overridable, so that you can override all of the default functions, regenerate the application and not lose your overrides. The database controls live in the page container, but have their own class definitions (i.e., their code-behind) in specific /app_code files. Again, each control type has its own base class with pretty completely overridable methods. A single record control (showing a single db record) is pretty simple. A table, showing several records, has a table class and a table row class. The ISD website (www.ironspeed.com/support) has good documentation of the ISD model as a whole.

So, where are the problems in this model?
1. Easy and tempting to live with their out of the box GUI. Point ISD at your database, pick the tables you want to have it turn in to pages, tell it the kinds of pages, give it a thematic style and five minutes later you're viewing the application. Cool. But, it is very easy to forget that their user GUI is probably not what your user wants to see. So, be prepared to think for yourself and tinker with the GUI thus created. Not hard to do, and you can use VS 2005 to help you.

2. Business objects. You could put together your own business objects, but it would be difficult and you would get no help from ISD. ISD does a LOT of building of simple validation and checking (appropriate look up values, ranges, lengths, etc.) ISD lets you build custom queries, but these are read-only. It is smart enough (and you can override the write from a page in any case) to let you take a one to many view and write it back to the database (you'd probably override the default base method, but it isn't that hard to do). However, when you get in to serious dependency checking, ISD is still really about tables and not business objects. So, you're going to write some code.

If you are smart, you'll write it once store it in app_code somewhere and use it by calling it from an overridden method in your table or record controls. If you are like most of us, you'll first spaghetti it in to one of the code-behind classes above, and then forget you did so, or have a copy in each of the 10 pages that manipulates customer data. In my world, that has usually meant 5 identical functions and 5 that are all different (even though they are all supposed to be the same). ISD makes it tempting to order marinara, because the model lends itself to spaghetti code. Of course, you can completely prevent this, but you gotta learn the ISD model to determine the best way to do it on your project.

3. Page state and postbacks. Although ISD is quite open about this problem and tells users not to just take the defaults of returning the whole asp.net page state in the postback stream (cache on the server instead), the default is to return the whole page. Can make for some BIG pages. Which makes users think S L O W. As I said, you can manipulate this. But, what newbie is going to get this when it is SO tempting to just point, click, and boom - instant application. Your manager is now off your back because her product inventory table is "on the web" with a cool search and edit GUI (of 400kb state pages if you've gone a bit nuts and have just taken the default behaviors of ISD). Great in-house, but the customers in the real world....

Again, knowledge is the key. You can fix this, but you need to know you SHOULD.

4. Database read/write postbacks. No big problem here, but you also need to know that the model is to fetch only the data used at the moment. If your table shows 1000 records in 50 record increments, when you go from records 1 to 50 to 51 through 100, you will postback and hit the database again. This keeps data current, but increases server traffic.

Overall: Try the demo version. Point it at something simple that you really want to turn in to an asp.net application. Build maybe three tables. Then dissect it using the above as a guide. See what YOU think and post back to this question.

Comment: I did try the demo and did end up buying it.  I'm thrilled (thus far). Thanks for your comment.

Comment: This is a realy good describ of iron speed. I don't like Iron speed that much because it creates good design, i agree with that, but the code of the data acces layer and the business access layer is quite heavy, with fuctions that are already programed and do not satisfy my needs in therm of data binding, NOT AT ALL. Why isin't ther an option that allows you to create the web pages design, but without creating the code that comes with them, that would be siimply genius.

Answer (score 2):

I have used it for convenience for a very small project. It did what I wanted and saved me a couple of days work.

The main problem I found was when it came to customising or extending the generated project. You have to spend quite a bit of time trying to understand Ironspeed's way of doing things which, I'll admit, is not my way.

I'd use it again for a small project if I knew in advance I wouldn't have to customise it much after.

Answer (score 1):

If stored procedure generation is all you are after, CodeSmith is a decent option at a fraction of the cost of IronSpeed.  There are several sproc templates available, and you can create your own or tweak an existing if that is what you need.  You can also gen .Net code to your hearts content with CodeSmith. Tons of business class templates already exist for this.

IronSpeed's value is not in the sproc generation, but in the RAD features.  I agree with @Galwegian...  IronSpeed is OK for mock ups or very simple apps, not so good at all if you need to do *any* customization.

Comment: I just looked at CodeSmith and it looks like it generates templates not actual pages with grids/textboxes etc.  That's probably good for people who need just code but I wanted to develop the application with databound objects (grids etc) not just code.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out Evolutility CRUD framework. It provides some of the same features (limited to CRUD) and is open source.

Answer (score 1):

IronSpeed has been great (out-of-the-box) at helping me develop data-driven corporate Intranet applications. While the code model takes a little getting used to, it is effective at maintaining a nice three-tier app. While the page templates can appear garish compared to 2010's web-design, it gets the job done, when you need function over form.

Answer (score 0):

Iron Speed Designer is great for simple CRUD type web applications. You can find some useful information on our web site http://www.dotnetarchitect.co.uk/